# How can I use eval() properly to append a dynamically loaded script's contents to an object being constructed?

Tags: javascript, constructor, eval

**How can I use eval() properly to append a dynamically loaded script's contents to an object being constructed?**

I'm working on a simple implementation of `require` for my own client-side use. There are multiple libraries for this, but for the sake of learning, I'm writing a very simple one.

This code should create a module `playBall` and in the same step require the two modules that contain code to create and move the ball.

So I have two simple modules (files) to be required:

**`example.com/createBall.js`**:

```
var exports = {};
var exports.createBall = function (){ 
    $("body").append("<div id=\'ball\'></div>") 
}
```

**`example.com/moveBall.js`**:

```
var exports = {};
var exports.moveBall = function (){ 
    $("#ball").animate({ marginTop : 300 },500) 
}
```

This require function simply performs AJAX calls to grab scripts based on the locations passed to the `Module` constructor.

```js
var Library = {};

// ..snip.. (The code within the mockAJAXCall is irrelevant)

//define resource requirement functionality
Library.require = function (resourceName, callback) {
    Library.mockAJAXCall(resourceName, function (mockResponse) {

        //return the response to the module requiring the resource
        callback(mockResponse);
    });

};

//define module prototype
Library.Module = function () {
    var _this = this;
    this.resources = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        Library.require(arguments[i], function (resource) {
            _this.resources[resource.location] = resource;
            for (var i in _this.resources){
                eval(); // ! eval the resource in a way that assigns 
                        // all of the functions and variables to _this
            }
        });
    }
};

//utilize requirement
var playBall = new Library.Module('example.com/createBall.js', 
    'example.com/moveBall.js');

playBall.createBall();
playBall.moveBall();
```

```css
#ball {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background-color:red;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:maroon;
}
```

The important piece of that snippet is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _this.resources.length; i++){
    eval(); // ! eval the resource in a way that assigns 
            // all of the functions and variables to _this
}
```

I'm not sure how to `eval()` the required scripts so that the contents of the `exports` object in each are appended to the `_this` object.

Comment: You know what they say about `eval()`...

Comment: @JLRishe [yes I do.](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)

Comment: `var exports.createBall = ` is a syntax error. Are you planning to do string-replacing on the scripts you receive?

Comment: Also, `_this.resources` is an object and does not have a `.length` property?

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I would have noticed those errors after I got the eval function working, thanks, Ill fix them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommmend to use the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) instead of `eval` (though you could do the same with an evaled IEFE). That way, you

- get a "module" scope for free
- don't collide with the scopes of the loader function
- can pass arguments with arbitrary names

```
(new Function("exports", ressourceCode))(ressourceObject);
```